# How to set up a ssh tunnel from a python program

Tags: python, linux, ssh, pymysql

(please, if you have an answer, please post a tested script, because I've tried the perfect theoretical script and it didn't work)

I have a cronjob in python that connects to an external server through a ssh tunnel to read and write a MySQL database there.

The python program opens a ssh tunnel and binds the mysql port to a local one, then connects to the external db through the pymysql library as if it were local.

Everything works fine, but... I couldn't make the tunnel to be opened and closes by the same program. So, I have to manually open a tunnel and let it open with the -f -N -T params to the shh.

It works ok, but I'd like that the progam could manage the tunnel without need of leaving a tunnel open. I couldn't get the right parameters for this.

I've read on Internet some answers that implies waiting for tunnel to open, and then shutting down by killing de process in the os. I don't like those solutions. In fact, I could do this in the past with this commands:

```
sys_command = "ssh -T -f user@external.server -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -p 22222 -L 3310:localhost:3306"    
            prog = subprocess.Popen(sys_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , stderr=subprocess.PIPE , shell = True)
            out,err = prog.communicate()
```

and then I connected to the db with:

```
con_test = pymysql.connect(user=conf.dbUser, passwd=conf.dbPass, host='localhost', port = 3310, db=conf.database)
```

It worked in another environment, but when I try it now I get:

> Cannot fork into background without a command to execute.

I've tried with a lot of combinations of parameters. The only one that worked was:

```
ssh -f -N -T .....
```

But, as I said, this opens a tunnel indefinitely.

I've also tried using Popen as it should be (separating parameter per parameter with quotes and commas and with Shell = False):

```
sys_command = ["ssh","-f","-T","user@external.server","-i","/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa","-p","22222","-L","3310:localhost:3306"]

prog = subprocess.Popen( sys_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , stderr=subprocess.PIPE , shell = False)
```

but i get the same error.

But, oh surprise, if I make a trick that I red by there and I add "sleep","10" to the end:

```
sys_command = ["ssh","-f","-T","user@external.server","-i","/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa","-p","22222","-L","3310:localhost:3306","sleep","10"]
```

...I get the greeting from the other server through outerr!
and, below, the error:

> bind: Cannot assign requested address

So, if someone knows a correct way to do it, please answer with a tested script, because many solutions I found in internet just didn't work in my environment.

Thanks in advance.